# No puedo cargar scripts de Jquery en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

Tengo el siguiente sitio, el cual está hecho en Wordpress:

http://www.endeavor.cl/

Quiero agregar una ventan de popup, por lo cual elegí usar jquery-ui. Sigo las indicaciones tal como salen aquí y no pasa nada:

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Fuí al archivo header.php de mi template y ahí agregué esto:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
```

Y en el mismo header.php también agregué esto:

```html
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Aquí está mi header.php completo, no sé qué puedo estar haciendo mal. No es sólo esto, también he probado con modales de Bootstrap y nada. Lo único que me funciona es el alert() de Javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<?php if (have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post(); endwhile; endif;?>
<!-- the default values -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="570150036476648" />
 
<!-- if page is content page -->
<?php
if (in_category('categoria-videos')) { ?>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/<?php the_field('video-youtube-id'); ?>/hqdefault.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300"/>
<?php } elseif (is_single()) { ?>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' ); ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $feat_image;?>" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300"/>
<?php } elseif (is_page()) { ?>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?> | <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Endeavor lidera el movimiento global que busca impulsar el crecimiento económico sostenible, a través de la selección de Emprendedores de Alto Impacto" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/FotoShare.jpg" /> 
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="450"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="298"/>
<?php } elseif(is_home()) { ?>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Endeavor Chile | www.endeavor.cl" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Endeavor lidera el movimiento global que busca impulsar el crecimiento económico sostenible, a través de la selección de Emprendedores de Alto Impacto" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/FotoShare.jpg" /> 
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="450"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="298"/>
<?php } else { ?>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Endeavor lidera el movimiento global que busca impulsar el crecimiento económico sostenible, a través de la selección de Emprendedores de Alto Impacto" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/FotoShare.jpg" /> 
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="450"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="298"/>
<?php } ?>

<title>
 <?php
 // Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
 global $page, $paged;

 wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

 // Add the blog name.
 bloginfo( 'name' );

 // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
 $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
 if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
  echo " | $site_description";

 // Add a page number if necessary:
 if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
  echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

 ?>
</title>
    
    
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<!-- Fancybox -->
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/fancybox/lib/fancyincludes.php'); ?>

<!-- Nicescroll -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>

<!-- Masonry -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/isotope/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<!-- PARALLAX -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/parallax/parallax.js"></script>

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/popup/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/popup/jquery.modal.min.css" type="text/css" />

<script>

 $(window).load(function() {
  <!---- MASONRY --->

  var $container = $('.grid');
  // initialize
  $container.isotope({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });
  <!---- MASONRY --->
 });



$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.show').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()+100;

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},300);

        }

    }); 

});





$(window).on('load resize', function () {  
  if ($(window).width() >= 1000){ 
   $("#menu-top").removeClass();
   $("#menu-top").addClass("desktop");
  }else{
   $("#menu-top").removeClass();
   $("#menu-top").addClass("touch");
   $("#menu-top.touch .menu-item-has-children a").addClass("primer-boton").css('cursor','pointer');
   $("#menu-top.touch .sub-menu a").removeClass();
   $("#menu-top.touch .primer-boton").removeAttr("href");
   $('#menu-top.touch .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').parent().click(function() {
     var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
     if ( $(submenu).is(':hidden') ) {
    $(submenu).slideDown(200);
     } else {
    $(submenu).slideUp(200);
     }
   });
   
  }

 });


 <!---- NICESCROLL --->
 var nice = false;
 $(document).ready(
   function() { 
  nice = $("html").niceScroll();
   }
 );
 <!---- NICESCROLL --->


 <!---- MENU --->
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav-mobile-hold").click(function(){
   $("#menu-top").slideToggle();
            $("#nav-mobile").toggleClass('active');
  });
  
 });
 <!---- MENU --->
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#post-content a[href$="jpg"], #post-content a[href$="png"], #post-content a[href$="jpeg"]').fancybox();
 });
 
 
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-45413975-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '570150036476648',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<?php include('includes/preload.php'); ?>


<div id="header">
    
    <div id="menu-top" class="menu-top">
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu_sup', 'menu_class' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => '') ); ?>
 </div>
    
    
    <div class="barra-menu">
          
        


     <div id="nav-mobile-hold">
      <div class="texto">menu</div>
            <div id="nav-mobile">
                <span class="ln-one"></span>
                <span class="ln-two"></span>
                <span class="ln-three"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><img id="logo-top" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/logo-top.svg"></a>
        <div id="redes-top">
            
            <div id="searchbox" >
             <form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" role="search">
                 <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Buscar…', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
                    <button type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-default right"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white">></span></button>
               </form> 
            </div>
 
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Endeavor-Chile-343478338971/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><img id="facebook-top" class="boton" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/iconos/facebook-blanco.svg"></a>
 
            <a href="https://twitter.com/endeavorchile" target="_blank"><img id="twitter-top" class="boton" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/iconos/twitter-blanco.svg"></a>
 
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/endeavorCL" target="_blank"><img id="youtube-top" class="boton" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/iconos/youtube-blanco.svg"></a>
            <a href="https://cl.linkedin.com/in/endeavorchile" target="_blank"><img id="linkedin-top" class="boton" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/template/iconos/linkedin-blanco.svg"></a>
            
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <?php include('includes/prox-evento.php'); ?>
    
</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la consola de JavaScript de tu navegador. Con seguridad verás el error que está ocurriendo.

Es probable que estés cargando dos versiones de jQuery y por eso no funcione, o bien el archivo jQuery esté en el lugar equivocado.

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<div id="dialog" title="Diálogo Básico" color="#DDD">
  <p>
    Estás cargando mal los archivos de jQuery.
  </p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

En general y a menos que hayas hecho el tema a mano, editar los archivos de un tema se considera una mala práctica. Es mejor editar los cambios en el archivo [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) y aún mejor [crear un *plugin*](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users) donde puedas aplicar los cambios que creas necesarios a cualquier tema.

El método adecuado para usar una versión de jQuery distinta a la que usa WordPress (y en general para cualquier script y/o hoja de estilo) es primero [registrarlo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) y después [*encolarlo*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Por ejemplo, para registrar y encolar `jquery-ui` a tu tema, tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.12.1', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery-ui' );
```

Con esto, registras el script `jquery`, específicas dónde se obtiene y las dependencias (en este caso `jquery`).

> ## Nota
>
> En realidad, WordPress [**ya incluye**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#defaults) `jquery-ui-dialog` en su instalación. Revisa la lista en este enlace: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#defaults.

---

> ## Nota 2 - La función wp_head()
>
> La función `wp_head()` es un *"gancho"* que nos ayuda a *colgar* de manera controlada y ordenada scripts y hojas de estilo en un tema. Se coloca antes de `</head>` para que WordPress y los plugins que lo necesiten inserten sus dependencias. *En mi opinión, el uso de `wp_head()` es obligatorio*.  **Deberías considerar la posibilidad de añadir esta función a tu tema.**

---

### Alternativa

Si por alguna razón decides no usar la función `wp_head()`, intenta colocando `jquery` al inicio del header... digamos después de la etiqueta `</title>`.

Comment: ¿Entonces no necesito registrar jquery-ui-dialog en functions.php?

Comment: Intenta primero la alternativa. Si tu diseñaste el tema, te tomará bastantes recursos hacer que encaje en los estándares de diseño y buenas prácticas de WordPress, por lo que tal vez te convenga solo hacer que funcione.

Comment: Yo no diseñé este theme, lo hizo un programador y a mí me encargaron ponerle un popup en el home. Probé instalando varios plugins de popups  y luego llamarlos con shortcodes, incluso usando echo do_shortcode['nombredelshortcode'] y no hubo caso. Por eso ahora me decanté por lo de hacerlo sólo con JQuery, lo cual tampoco está funcionando. La única cosa que me funciona son los "alert()" de Javascript.

Comment: Debe ser por lo que comento en la nota 2.

Comment: Este theme tiene todas las hojas de estilo y scripts declaradas en el head. ¿Tengo entonces que sacar todo de ahí primero y ponerlas en el functions.php con enqueue_script?

Comment: Creo que estamos repitiendo lo mismo: Lee la nota dos y la alternativa.... en este asunto no hay nada obligatorio, todo depende de tu competencia.

Comment: Agregué la función wp_head() al inicio del header.php y ahora apareció el contenido de un plugin que ya tenían instalado llamado Sumo.Me que incluso hace popups anunciando cosas. Pensé que quizás con eso podría llegar e instalar un plugin de popup, pero los instalo, configuro y el popup no aparece.

Comment: Modificar tu tema usando `wp_head()` es un tema completamente distinto a lo que preguntas aquí, por lo que te recomiendo que hagas una nueva pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].